# Save DataFrame to Table - performance in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I know there are two ways to save a DF to a table in Pyspark:

```
1) df.write.saveAsTable("MyDatabase.MyTable")

2) df.createOrReplaceTempView("TempView")
   spark.sql("CREATE TABLE MyDatabase.MyTable as select * from TempView")
```

Is there any difference in performance using a "CREATE TABLE AS " statement vs "saveAsTable" when running on a large distributed dataset?

Answer (score 3):

`createOrReplaceTempView` creates (or replaces if that view name already exists) a lazily evaluated "view" that can be uses as a table in Spark SQL. It is not materialized until you call an action (like `count`) or persisted to `memory` unless you call `cache` on the dataset that underpins the view. As the name suggests, this is just a **temporary** view. It is lost after your application/session ends.

`saveAsTable` on the other hand saves the data to external stores like `hdfs` or `s3` or `adls`. This is permanent storage and lasts longer than scope of the SparkSession or Spark Application and is available for use later.

So the main difference is on the **lifetime** of dataset than the performance. Obviously, within the same job, working with cached data is faster.

Comment: `.cache()` by itself doesn't materialize dataset either. The question is about `.saveAsTable` vs `spark.sql(CTAS)`.

Comment: @mazaneicha read my answer again. it clearly says you need to call an "action" to materialize. :-)

Comment: @AravindYarram, Thanks for your comment, but I this is not answering my question.
I am asking about what is the best way to save the data to external store. Is there any difference using saveAsTable or spark.sql(CTAS) or even spar.sql(INSERT INTO...) ?